# xamarin.mac application crash report

Tags: c#, cocoa, crash-reports, xamarin.mac

my application crashed unexpectedly, I couldn't  catch what the any exception... I have registered handler :

```
static void Main (string [] args)
        {
            NSApplication.Init ();
            NSApplication.Main (args);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleUnhandledException;
        }


        static void HandleUnhandledException (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //Log the exception...
            FileHelper.CreateLogFile ("app crash", e.ExceptionObject.ToString ());
        }
```

But it is not called .

Also, I can't   see any report inside :

> ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

Is there any way to see crash reports of my application ?

Answer (score 4):

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException only fires when you have a **managed** exception happen, bubble up the entire stack. However, if you are crashing in native code, or with an NSException in native code, or throwing a managed exception while being called back from native code, it will likely not do what you want / be called at all.

Try this instead:

```
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.MarshalManagedException += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine (args.Exception);
};
```

You can also look into these options on mmp marshal-objectivec-exceptions and marshal-managed-exceptions (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/tools/common/Driver.cs#L24).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `NSApplication.Main (args);` runs your application with a main loop, so it never gets to the line to attach the unhandled exception until you quit your application.

Try this instead:

```
    static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        NSApplication.Init ();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleUnhandledException;

        NSApplication.Main (args);
    }


    static void HandleUnhandledException (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //Log the exception...
        FileHelper.CreateLogFile ("app crash", e.ExceptionObject.ToString ());
    }
```